# Hide Subscription Price & Details WooCommerce for Free Sample

Tags: woocommerce, cart, subscription, price

A customer would like to offer a free trial of her subscription services. For some reason WooCommerce details the full price of the subscription next to the Free Sample item within the cart. We'd like the price next to this specific item not be shown in the cart.

I thought it'd be easiest to just edit the CSS to not display the price. So far the code I have below will remove all prices from cart and checkout. I'd like only to remove the price from a specific product. How can I edit this to target the one product?

.shop_table thead, .shop_table .amount {display:none; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the .CSS code manually or you can simply download this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-custom-price-label/installation/
and install it on your WordPress site. Don't be worried, the free version will work. Simply go to the product you wish to make this change to and you'll see "custom price labels", check enable under "instead of the price" and then update the product. 
Hope this helps!
-Zuuchq

Comment: Actually, that did do most of it! Now, i just need to target product totals on that Cart page and hide that, and I've got it. Thank you!